# What are good UCI-compatible GUIs for Mac?

Tags: engines, uci

Is anyone running a UCI-compatible GUI on a Mac?  Preferably something native and modern, so WINE and Rosetta (etc) are not needed.  My goal is to simply set up chess positions and let Stockfish analyze.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scid is what I use. It's compiled to [a native app](http://scid.sourceforge.net/download.html). It seems to work fairly well for this purpose, although Stockfish 2.2.2 is acting weird, you might try 2.1.1 if you have problems. I actually [wrote a howto](http://wes.skeweredrook.com/analyzing-chess-games-with-scid-and-stockfish-on-mac-osx-lion/), even though it's fairly simple.

I've recently been running Stockfish with multiple variations turned up to 100, so it looks at all moves deeply, which you wouldn't want to do during a game, but for analysis that you plan to run a long time, it catches some unlikely good moves earlier.

Comment: Both links are now broken.

Comment: Sorry about that; I should probably recreate my blog somewhere.

Answer (score 9):

Wow, I usually wouldn't add another answer like this, but I've been quite impressed by the fork of Scid called [Scid vs PC](http://scidvspc.sourceforge.net/) (which is more actively maintained, and has a mac distribution called Scid vs Mac). I found it while looking for mac build instructions for Scid while trying to make scid do a better job of processing stockfish's input. (and by the way, Scid vs PC doesn't fix the stockfish 2.2+ problem, as it still depends on the tcl one line at a time input parsing).